# Python - scrape HTML to csv in neat table(s) format

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I got the python script below and the purpose is to scrape HTML and save it to csv in nest table(s) format.

[image]

Can anyone could help? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try declaring the url as unicode `url = u'http://www.aastocks.com/en/cnhk/market/quota-balance/hk-connect'`

Comment: Hi Jared, I got error msg after try declaring the rul as uicod: IndentationError: expected an indented block.
And I also try to [Tab] before df.to_csv('C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\PyTest\output.csv' % i)
it still have the indentation error, how should I do?

Comment: is it `python2` or `python3`? Probably `python2` and you fall in encoding problem.

Comment: mine is python3.6

Comment: read about string formatting [here](https://pyformat.info/) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried your code(with small modification) and it works:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.aastocks.com/en/cnhk/market/quota-balance/hk-connect'

for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_html(url)):
    filename = '/tmp/output_%02d.csv' % i
    df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')
```

Output:

```
daniel@synapse:/tmp$ cat output_17.csv
,0,1,2,3,4,5
0,Combined Southbound,,,,,
1,Date,Daily Quota Balance(% of Quota),Money Flow,Buy Trade Value(HKD),Sell Trade Value(HKD),Total Trade Value1 (% of Market Turnover)
2,2018/02/07,20.68B(98.46%),In 322.87M,TBA,TBA,TBA
3,2018/02/06,12.98B(61.81%),In 8.02B,25.70B,18.10B,43.80B(16.98%)
4,2018/02/05,10.76B(51.25%),In 10.24B,19.50B,8.91B,28.41B(16.72%)
5,2018/02/02,15.60B(74.29%),In 5.40B,12.43B,7.05B,19.48B(13.17%)
6,2018/02/01,18.67B(88.90%),In 2.33B,11.60B,9.89B,21.49B(13.90%)
7,2018/01/31,14.89B(70.91%),In 6.11B,14.29B,8.32B,22.61B(12.79%)
8,2018/01/30,17.55B(83.55%),In 3.45B,11.82B,8.86B,20.68B(11.92%)
9,2018/01/29,16.24B(77.35%),In 4.76B,14.98B,10.45B,25.43B(13.27%)
10,2018/01/26,17.53B(83.46%),In 3.47B,12.01B,9.20B,21.21B(11.79%)
11,2018/01/25,18.18B(86.58%),In 2.82B,13.09B,11.13B,24.22B(12.90%)
12,2018/01/24,17.02B(81.07%),In 3.98B,13.42B,10.13B,23.55B(12.54%)
13,2018/01/23,14.72B(70.07%),In 6.28B,15.35B,9.39B,24.74B(12.50%)
14,2018/01/22,14.77B(70.31%),In 6.23B,14.43B,8.21B,22.64B(13.40%)
15,2018/01/19,14.75B(70.26%),In 6.25B,13.86B,7.68B,21.54B(13.25%)
16,2018/01/18,14.78B(70.36%),In 6.22B,15.07B,8.94B,24.01B(12.23%)
17,,,,,,
```

**FYI:** page charset=UTF-8

### UPDATE on comment

> I use excel to open csv and find the contents is garbled.

I didn't find any Chinese chars, but if I will change URL to `url = 'http://www.aastocks.com/sc/cnhk/market/quota-balance/hk-connect'`, so Chinese shown properly.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.aastocks.com/sc/cnhk/market/quota-balance/hk-connect'

for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_html(url, encoding='utf-8')):
    filename = '/tmp/output_%02d.csv' % i
    df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')
```

**Check output:**

```
daniel@synapse:/tmp$ head -5 output_17.csv
,0,1,2,3,4,5
0,南向合计,,,,,
1,日期,每日额度馀额(占额度),当日资金流向,买入成交额(港元),卖出成交额(港元),总成交额1(佔大市成交%)
2,2018/02/07,218.69亿(104.14%),流出8.69亿,163.10亿,188.78亿,351.88亿(16.12%)
3,2018/02/06,129.79亿(61.81%),流入80.21亿,257.05亿,180.96亿,438.01亿(16.98%)
```

So I think the problem with encoding in `excel`(fix me if Im wrong).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply because of work..
I tried the following:
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.aastocks.com/en/cnhk/market/quota-balance/hk-connect'

for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_html(url)):
    filename = 'C:/Users/Lawrence/Desktop/PyTest/output.csv' % i
    df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')

However, it returns error msg:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: because you are trying to format string `'C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\PyTest\output.csv' % i`, but what to format? Where is flag for formatting? Do you see my implementation - `'/tmp/output_%02d.csv' % i`? do you see `%02d` flag? where is your flag?

Comment: Thank you sKwa, it works well. I use excel to open csv and find the contents is garbled. (it should be in Chinese), how can it be readable?

Comment: @YungLinMa `pandas` fails to parse page properly. `pandas` requires that data will be in `HTML tables` and static page, i.e. not populated by javascript. In your case table populated by js.

Comment: How can I download dynamic website to csv. Could you please offer me the codes. Thank you and you are really knowledgeable and helpful :)

Comment: @YungLinMa, actually its a complicated question. try to google `python web scraping`. Can you point on table that isn't parsed properly and maybe I will find a quick workaround?

Comment: @YungLinMa, I was wrong, my bad, sorry. I just checked and I have to say that now its problem with encoding in `excel` and I'm not an expert in `excel`. You need to read data with encoding `utf-8 no bom` in `excel`.

Comment: http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/futures/index.php
the above dynamic website cannot be scrape by pandas, how to do it?

Comment: @YungLinMa, as I said it's a broad and complicated question, google it: `python web scrapping`. You need to emulate browser  behavior and not all pages you can parse(some sites prevent pages parsing with robots). I updated my answer, check it.